# (jquery) .load and .live

Tags: jquery

I've loaded content1.html into a div using .load (WHICH WORKS FINE).

Now I want to put a link in the content1.html content that when clicked would load content2.html into the div.  Any ideas how I would do this? At the moment I've got:

```
google.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
    $('#howtoguide6').live('click', function() {

        $("#howtoguide6").click(function(){
            $("#hiw-content-area").load("pages/hiw/how_to.html");
            return false;
        });
    });
});
```

Basicly I've already loaded

```
google.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
$("#choose_design_service").click(function(){
    $("#hiw-content-area").load("pages/hiw/what_we_need_from_you.html");
    return false;
    });
});
```

-which works fine, I now have want to add something to "pages/hiw/what_we_need_from_you.html"
that will load "pages/hiw/how_to.html" into the "#hiw-content-area".

I think where I'm having trouble is doing this from inside already loaded content.

Comment: why are you calling twice the click() event?

Comment: do the links to load content1.html, and the link *inside* content1.html have the same id?  #howtoguide6?  They probably shouldn't, which might be part of your issue.

Answer (score 4):

I assume (you don't explain which element is which), that you want:

```
$('#howtoguide6').live('click', function() {
    $("#hiw-content-area").load("pages/hiw/how_to.html");
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Take out the call to `click()'.

```
google.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
    $('#howtoguide6').live('click', function() {
            $("#hiw-content-area").load("pages/hiw/how_to.html");
            return false;
    });
});
```

---

Your original code wasn't working because `click()` is a shortcut to the function `bind('click')`. `live()` is similar to `bind()`, except that the results of the selector do not have to exist in the DOM. So your code was binding a function to click that bound the function to click again, rather than running the code in the handler.

Taking out the call to click will simply run the handler when the element is clicked, since (you have bound to the element using `live()`.

Answer (score 0):

what i don't understand is the second click binding. have you tried :

```
google.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
$('#howtoguide6').live('click', function() {
        $("#hiw-content-area").load("pages/hiw/how_to.html");
        return false;
});
```

});